# Use of having two try-catch?

Tags: java, try-catch

What is the benefit of having two try-catch as seen below? Taken from the book Beginning Hibernate.

```
protected void rollback() {
        try {
            getSession().getTransaction().rollback();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            // TODO change to log
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        try {
            getSession().close();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            // TODO change to log
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: presumably because you want to close the session irrespective of whether the operation succeeds or not.

Comment: Why don't you just use a finally block?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It guarantees that `close()` will be invoked, even if `rollback()` throws an exception.

Comment: It's better use the close() on finally block fot that purpose.

Comment: @mre in case the exception that will be thrown from rollbadk is not HibernateException, for example any RuntimeException

Answer (score 2):

The initial purpose was to close the session even if the rollback() method throws an exception but this solutions is not good enough.

If roolback throws a RuntimeException the close code will never be called

You should do the following:

```
protected void rollback() {
        try {
            getSession().getTransaction().rollback();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            // TODO change to log
            System.out.println(e);
        } finally {
            try {
                getSession().close();
            } catch (HibernateException e) {
                // TODO change to log
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    }
```

This ensures that the close code will be called no matter what.

Comment: @Chin Boon  As a general practice, you should do the "close()" operation inside "finally" block, so that you ensure that it always gets executed. This code block can then itself have its own try - catch block.

Answer (score 0):

None, really. If you replace that code with

```
protected void rollback() {
        try {
            getSession().getTransaction().rollback();
            getSession().close();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            // TODO change to log
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
```

you still get pretty much the same info. There are some minute differences:

in the first case, the line `getSession().close();` will still be called even if `getSession().getTransaction().rollback();` throws an exception, while in my example it will not. The proper way to handle this however is to use a finally block if you want that .close() line to be called no matter what.

Comment: no need for a finally, you'd presumably want to catch any exceptions thrown during the `close()` operation too..

Comment: You'll still need to use a try-catch in the finally block though. This just ends up making the method more verbose.

Comment: Not really, if your last .close() operation thows an exception you don't really want to catch that as there's no real good way to recover from it. I agree however that it's just a matter of taste.

Comment: @AndreiBodnarescu, My comment was made with the assumption that OP didn't want the method to throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is independence between these parts. Both parts may fail independently. (And handled independently as well). A fail of 'rollback' invocation won't prevent execution of 'close' statement, as opposite to a single try-catch block approach for this case.